# Как вызвать default приложение для отправки почты? (C++ Builder, Android)

Tags: android, c++, c++builder, email

На Java можно использовать Intent, но вот как вызвать другое приложение, а именно почтовое приложение, я не нашел. Вызов из своего приложения по кнопке.

Comment: Приложение под Android?

Comment: @alexolut приложение кросс-платформенное, под андройд соответсвенно тоже

Answer (score 1):

Нужно вызвать Java-код из C++ по средствам [JNI](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/articles/perf-jni.html). Например так:

Java

```
package com.package;
class PlatformUtils
{
    public static final void openEmailClient(final String address, final String subject, final String text)
    {
        // mailto:[ mail address ] [?] [subject=subject] [&cc=mail address] [&bcc=mail address] [&body=message body]
        String URI = ("mailto:" + (address == null ? "" : URLEncoder.encode(address, "utf-8").replace("+", "%20")));
        URI += ("?subject=" + (subject == null ? "" : URLEncoder.encode(subject, "utf-8").replace("+", "%20")));
        URI += ("&body=" + (text == null ? "" : URLEncoder.encode(text, "utf-8").replace("+", "%20")));

        final Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        Uri data = Uri.parse(URI);
        intent.setData(data);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

C++

```
void openEmailClient(const char* address, const char* subject, const char* text)
{
    JNIEnv* env = DGetJNIEnv();
    jclass cls = env->FindClass("com/package/PlatformUtils");
    if(cls)
    {
        jmethodID meth = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "openEmailClient", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V");
        if(meth)
        {
            jstring param_address = env->NewStringUTF(address == null ? "" : address);
            jstring param_subject = env->NewStringUTF(subject == null ? "" : subject);
            jstring param_text = env->NewStringUTF(text == null ? "" : text);
            env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, meth, param_address, param_subject, param_text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `jclass cls = env->FindClass("com/package/PlatformUtils");`
Конкретный путь в папке с проектом указывать надо?

Comment: @UliyanRomanov это полное имя java-класса с пакетом. В примере это com.package.PlatformUtils. В FindClass точки заменяются на слеши.

Comment: DGetJNIEnv(); - такого метода нет у меня

Comment: @UliyanRomanov не знаю комплектацию вашего компилятора, но обычно #include "jni.h" помогает.

Comment: Это может показаться смешным, но что такое context? Мы Intellij IDEA предлагает инициализировать null это. Без context будет startactivity подчеркивать. Я воспользовался более коротким методом, но там есть такое `if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
           startActivity(intent);`

`getPackageManager()` и `startActivity(intent)` подчеркивает. На это не стоит обращать внимание?

Answer (score 1):

Тот же intent и юзайте

http://blong.com/Articles/DelphiXE5AndroidActivityResult/ActivityResult.htm#EmailActivity

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28956563/how-to-send-email-with-attachment-using-default-android-email-app-delphi-xe7

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNIBridge, ...

...

procedure CreateEmail(const Recipient, Subject, Content: string); overload;
var
  Intent: JIntent;
begin
  Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_SEND);
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_EMAIL, StringToJString(Recipient));
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_SUBJECT, StringToJString(Subject));
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_TEXT, StringToJString(Content));
  // Intent.setType(StringToJString('plain/text'));
  Intent.setType(StringToJString('message/rfc822'));
  // LaunchActivity(Intent);
  LaunchActivity(TJIntent.JavaClass.createChooser(Intent, StrToJCharSequence('Which email app?')));
end;
```

Только на плюсы с паскаля переписать. Вам на билдере не привыкать ))